# Why different frames of same video have different sizes?

Tags: video, frame-size

In a video I am working on, I had to split the video into frames. But I have noticed the size of most of the frame is different. A solid white frame have a size of 2KB but some have the size of 36KB. Why is that? All the frames have same height, width, same number of pixels, same bit depth. So why the sizes are different? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Compression. If a frame is a single color, it can be represented in a very compact form. For example, I can describe a frame in English with the sentence: "1920 by 1080 pixels, all of them are white". And that only took 42 charters to describe the entire frame perfectly. Now If i was to describe the Mono Lisa to a person who has never seen it, so that can make an exact copy, it would take a lot more words.

The example I gave is called "Run length coding", and it is the simplest form of compression.